# Start multiple PowerShells with same keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Its really annoying i can only start first PoweShell with custom keyboard shortcut i assigned for it. And i usually need more then one PowerShell.
Also my PowerShell icon is default blank paper, seems like something might be broken?

Comment: You could start Console2 or ConsoleZ instead, and have it start multiple PowerShell tabs at once.  https://github.com/cbucher/console

Comment: I like cmder but its slow. I should probably check out those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pin PowerShell to your taskbar you can open a new PowerShell window by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+ the number corresponding to its position.  For example I have PowerShell in the eighth position so I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to open PowerShell.

If PowerShell is already open and I need an additional PowerShell window I can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.

If you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> while you already have multiple PowerShell windows open, it will cycle through the open windows.

Comment: Didn't know about Win+Shift+number. Thanks, this will be useful.

Comment: I didn't know about that either - Thanks!